# How to avoid duplicated code with 2 classes having the same methods but no common interface

Tags: java, generics

I have many places in my code where I have method that is identical to another one except objects they use are different as in below example:

```
private void applyContractualFields(){
 PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type recentPcmFieldType = getData();

 if (recentPcmFieldType != null) {
    paymentChangeMaintenance.setContractualFieldsApplied(true);
    if (recentPcmFieldType.getAnnualInterestRate() != null) {
        paymentChangeMaintenance.setContractualInterestRate(
                recentPcmFieldType.getAnnualInterestRate());
    }
    if (recentPcmFieldType.getPIAmount() != null) {
        paymentChangeMaintenance
                .setContractualPIAmount(recentPcmFieldType.getPIAmount());
    }
    paymentChangeMaintenance.setCountyTax(recentPcmFieldType.getCountyTaxAmount());
 }
}

private void applyPaymentDataFromPcmFields() {
 PaymentChangeMaintenanceCommonFieldsV214Type recentPcmFieldType = getData();

 if (recentPcmFieldType != null) {
    paymentChangeMaintenance.setContractualFieldsApplied(true);
    if (recentPcmFieldType.getAnnualInterestRate() != null) {
        paymentChangeMaintenance.setContractualInterestRate(
                recentPcmFieldType.getAnnualInterestRate());
    }
    if (recentPcmFieldType.getPIAmount() != null) {
        paymentChangeMaintenance
                .setContractualPIAmount(recentPcmFieldType.getPIAmount());
    }
    paymentChangeMaintenance.setCountyTax(recentPcmFieldType.getCountyTaxAmount(
 ));
 }
}
```

Is there a way to combine these two using generics?
Also, `PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type` and `PaymentChangeMaintenanceCommonFieldsV214Type` are auto-generated classes from wsdl file.

[image]

Comment: you could probably if `PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type` and `PaymentChangeMaintenanceCommonFieldsV214Type` would implement the same interface that would provide those getter/setters I guess

Comment: In the interest of helping you, a more concise example of your problem would be nice to have.

Comment: or maybe just use inheritance... if both have the same superclass or interface

Comment: @NicholasK because of the first line of each method. Look at the types of the two instances of `recentPcmFieldType`

Comment: @Angelina :  Do `PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type` and `PaymentChangeMaintenanceCommonFieldsV214Type` implement a common interface or extend a common class?

Comment: @NicholasK no, they don't.

Comment: If you have control over the wsdl files, please ensure that CommonFields inherits from Fields.

If you don't have control over the wsdl files, make sure to wrap your wsdl generated classes with your own classes implementing a shared interface (this will solve your issue in terms of code duplication and will also protect you from wsdl changes made by the other party)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `Wrapper` class that can accept either `PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type`  or `PaymentChangeMaintenanceCommonFieldsV214Type` (or `A` and `B` in the test code here), and delegates your calls to the underlying objects. 
 
Every time you receive an instance of `A` or `B` you construct an instance of a `Wrapper` and use it. 
This way the duplication of code is limited to within the `Wrapper`:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private final Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Main().test();
    }

    void test(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
            Object obj = getData();          //obj can be either A or B
            Wrapper w = new Wrapper(obj);    //construct a Wrapper 
            System.out.println(w.getName()); //use it 
        }
    }

    Object getData(){  //generate objects for testing 
        return rand.nextBoolean() ? new A() : new B(); // returns A half the times
    }
}

class Wrapper {

    Object obj;
    Wrapper(Object obj){ //throw an exception if obj is not an A or B 
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    String getName(){
        return obj instanceof A ? ((A)obj).getName() : ((B)obj).getName() ;
    }
}

//two classes implementing the same method without having a common interface 
class A {

    String getName() { return getClass().getSimpleName(); }
}

class B {

    String getName() { return getClass().getSimpleName(); }
}
```

By creating an appropriate wrapper you can make your method accept both types by changing one line:

```
 MyWrapper recentPcmFieldType = new MyWrapper(getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to use reflection. Here is a sample that should work according to the passed object. However, you have to handle exceptions and it would be nice to check of what class the passed object is.

```
private <T> void applyContractualFields(T t) { 
    try {
        Class<?> c = t.getClass();
        Method getPIAmount = c.getDeclaredMethod("getPIAmount");
        Integer piAmount = (Integer) getPIAmount.invoke(t);
        if (piAmount != null) {
             paymentChangeMaintenance.setContractualPIAmount(piAmount);
        }

        /* the rest ... */

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both classes are auto-generated from WSDL, so I assume he can not modify them. And if he can, he shouldn't, since any changes to WSDl will break his modifications.